# Can't get Java scanner pattern correct

Tags: java, io

NumberOfBankAccounts, bankname, balance, transaction name, category, cost, and these last 3 repeat for each transaction in said accounts name, till all transactions have been read and it reaches an empty line(end of current accounts data) and a new account starts on the next line. They are all on their own line, but wont let me show this on stack. I am saving each account with a space in between said account in the list as i said, and I can't get it to detect that space so it can break out of the transaction maker while loop to start a new account. This is my code:

```
private void loadFile(File save) throws FileNotFoundException {
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(save);
    int accnumber = Integer.parseInt(scanner.next());
    System.out.println(accnumber);
    for(int i = 0;i<=accnumber;i++){






        Account a  = new Account();

            a.setName(scanner.next());
            System.out.println(a.getName());
            a.setTotal(Double.parseDouble(scanner.next()));
            System.out.println(a.getTotal());
            while(scanner.hasNext()) {
                Transaction t = new Transaction();

                t.setCategory(scanner.next());
                System.out.println(t.getCategory());
                t.setDescription(scanner.next());
                System.out.println(t.getDescription()+" Description");
                t.setAmount(Double.parseDouble(scanner.next()));
                System.out.println(t.getAmount());
                a.TRANSACTION_LIST.add(t);
                if (scanner.nextLine().isEmpty()) {
                System.out.println("BREAKING");
                  break;
                }


        }



            AccountData.ACCOUNT_LIST.add(a);
            System.out.println(AccountData.ACCOUNT_LIST.size());


    }
```

It continues to get off track to the wrong line and attempt to parse a number from an actual word because it's off center and I believe its because of the line in between and not breaking out of its while loop. Please help me?

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is here:

```
       if (scanner.nextLine().isEmpty()) {
            System.out.println("BREAKING");
              break;
         }
```

You are eating the next line just to check if it is empty. If it isn't you have now lost that line and advanced the Scanner. You should have this block at the beginning of your loop and first assign the value of the line to a variable so the value is not lost.

Try changing your while loop to something like this:

```
String line = null;
while(!(line = keyboard.nextLine()).isEmpty()) {
```